# Use HTML5 input with Struts?

Tags: html, struts

Is it possible to convert my `<html:text...` in HTML5 format (type=email, number, etc...)
Is it possible with Struts tags ?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to take the existing tag library and convert then to output the new tags. If you do, you could file it as a patch I don't know of any efforts under way to do this for Struts 1, which is likely to be EOLed soon anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't know struts enought to developp new tag..
I'm suprize that nobody has wanted convert

Comment: Not too many people are doing new development with Struts 1, and essentially all work on it stopped a few years ago. Developing custom tags is relatively straight-forward; if you looked at the source for them I'm sure it'd be enough to get you started.