# can Struts Support HTML5?

Tags: java, database, struts

I have been using struts framework i have to implement HTML 5 on the application  is is possibke have makje changes in struts tag library?

since i have embeded all html tags like this

```
<html:form action="action.jsp" type="sample" name="applyform" >
```

can any one help?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497326/use-html5-input-with-struts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no html5 specific  taglib for Struts 1.x. (you tagged with 'struts', so I'm assuming that is what you are using). But you could write your own by extending the standard struts taglib. It shouldn't prove too difficult. Another option is to just use regular JSP EL/JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

Sruts 2 supports HTML5 elements in its tag library, see for example the reference for [textfield](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/tag-reference.html):

> Type: (…) Specifies the html5 type element to display. e.g. text, email, url